# How to calculate and store item property when rendering that item?

Tags: reactjs

I need to calculate and store values from items, what been filtered earlier by some criteria and rendered:

```
<ItemsList>
items ? 
  items.map(
  item => 
    someCriteria &&
    <ItemComponent details={item}>
  )
<ItemsList />
```

I need something like `let someVar += item.value` somewhere to use it **after map ends** and before criteria changes.
I cant store it on-fly in local state, because of re-rendering while *map* runs

I see the only way to do this, for now, is to store it in *localStorage*, but it is even more stupid, I think.

Because of app architecture there is no redux store, only one state in main file.
Thanks

Comment: I think you have a bit of an [X Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here, can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: this is invalid React code.

Comment: @ajmajmajma maybe so. I'm try to catch values from items, that are just rendered and use that values somewhere else. For example, for some reason two items are passed into rendered component as props, I want to know what will be sum of values of them (item.value) and store that sum to use, when map() ends  .   When another cas fires three items was filtered to be passed to rendered component - so I want sum of three values. And so on. I am support this app - so I m limited in methods to approach. I need to know how much items was passed and store them in safe place to use.

Comment: @Kunukn is right your syntax is wrong

Comment: @devsourav - it is not a React code obviously, that is a schema to explain. Problem is that I dont know how to store passed items when map() runs and use them when map() ends. I suppose there are more clever ways to do that, but I dont know .

Comment: @d2048 check my solution it was for react ofcourse. for the concept here is another small example:
`let val = [1,2,3];
let myvar = '';

let val2 = val.map(key => {
  myvar += key;
  return 'hello';
});`

after the map ends you can get the added value `console.log(myvar);`

Answer (score 1):

Though I don't quite understand what exactly you want to create. Here is something I think might be useful for you

```
var someVar = '';
const renderable = 
<ItemsList>
    { items ? 
        items.map( item => {
                if(someCriteria){
                    someVar += item.value;
                    return <ItemComponent details={item} key={a-must-key}>;
                }
            }
        )
        :
        null
    }
</ItemsList>
```

after the **map** end you can extract the value from the ***someVar***

Comment: The closing tag should be `</ItemsList>`

Comment: @devsourav - yes, I think it may be good to me. And  although my approach may be a crutch I will try this way. Thanx

Comment: @Kunukn sorry, it was by copy paste, you're right again 

Comment: @d2048 need an upvote please if it was useful to you 